# Jetpack compose navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have 2 screens in my navigation graph which are screen A and Screen B. I navigate to screen B from screen A. Now when I navigate back from screen B, Screen A gets recomposed. Why this behaviour is occurring and how can I prevent this so that on navigating back the screen is not recomposed. I am a beginner in jetpack compose. So it would be great for me if I could detailed explanation about this behaviour.
Thanks in advance